# pdflatex, latexmk, synctex: Adding an option to pdflatex causes synctex to fail

Tags: pdftex, latexmk, forward-inverse-search

The user "Mike" kindly helped me on [Latex, Emacs: automatically open *TeX Help* buffer on error and close it after correction of the error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249458/latex-emacs-automatically-open-tex-help-buffer-on-error-and-close-it-after-c) to create the following function which makes error detection to play nicely together with `latexmk`.

```
(defun run-latexmk ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((TeX-save-query nil)
        (TeX-process-asynchronous nil)
        (master-file (TeX-master-file)))
    (TeX-save-document "")
    (TeX-run-TeX "latexmk"
         (TeX-command-expand "latexmk -pdf %s" 'TeX-master-file)
                 master-file)
    (if (plist-get TeX-error-report-switches (intern master-file))
        (TeX-next-error t)
      (progn
    (demolish-tex-help)
    (minibuffer-message "latexmk: done.")))))
```

I would like to add another option to the `latexmk` call like this:

```
(TeX-command-expand "latexmk -pdflatex='pdflatex -file-line-error' -pdf %s" 'TeX-master-file)
```

to make `pdflatex` to report not only the line of an error but also the file name (which is crucial for AUCTeX to open the correct buffer in case of an error). The problem is that after I add this option, a compiled `myfile.tex` does not have an accompanying `myfile.synctex.gz` anymore, which causes forward and backward search to fail (see [How to set up Okular for forward/backward search with TeX Live 2011? (not trivial anymore)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60170/how-to-set-up-okular-for-forward-backward-search-with-tex-live-2011-not-trivia/60179#60179)).

Where is the problem?

Comment: Did you try putting `-synctex=1` `-file-line-error`?

Comment: Great, thanks, that worked! I guess I should have specified this option even without the pdflatex option, not sure why it was working automatically. Thanks again, egreg.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The

```
"latexmk -pdflatex='pdflatex -file-line-error' -pdf %s"
```

instruction should contain *all* options we want to pass to `pdflatex` at execution time, so

```
"latexmk -pdflatex='pdflatex -file-line-error -synctex=1' -pdf %s"
```

should work. The part within single quotes is the command `latexmk` will issue for compiling the document.