# How to set up texi2dvi with synctex and error handling?

Tags: pdftex, emacs, forward-inverse-search, texi2dvi

I would like to set up `texi2dvi` (with error-handling, synctex for forward and backward syncronization, and Okular as
viewer) to compile `.tex` documents (under Ubuntu 12.04 with Emacs 24).

(In case this matters) here is my general LaTeX/AUCTeX setup in `.emacs` (feel free to comment if you see nonsense here already):

```
;; basics
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp"); path to tex-site.el
(require 'tex-site); enable AUCTeX
(load "auctex.el" nil t t)
(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t); preview in .tex file
(setq TeX-auto-save t); enable parsing buffers on save 
(setq TeX-parse-self t); enable parsing buffers on load
(setq TeX-save-query nil); autosave before compiling (=> do not ask for saving)
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t); use pdflatex by default
(setq TeX-clean-confirm nil); don't ask for confirmation on cleaning via M-x TeX-clean
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode); turn on latex math mode
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill); turn on auto-fill mode
(setq-default TeX-master nil); for master/slave projects

;; start (first) emacs session in server mode (required for backward search from
;; .pdf to .tex)
;; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397323/how-to-avoid-the-message-of-server-start-while-opening-another-emacs-session
(require 'server)
(or (server-running-p)
    (server-start))
```

In case of an error, the TeX Help buffer should be displayed, indicating the error. If the
error is resolved and the `.tex` file compiled again, the buffer should
disappear. For the latter, we need the following function:

```
;; for closing the help buffer after all errors are resolved
;; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249458/latex-emacs-automatically-open-tex-help-buffer-on-error-and-close-it-after-c
(defun demolish-tex-help ()
  (interactive)
  (if (get-buffer "*TeX Help*")
      (progn
        (if (get-buffer-window (get-buffer "*TeX Help*"))
            (delete-window (get-buffer-window (get-buffer "*TeX Help*")))
          )
        (kill-buffer "*TeX Help*")
        )
    )
  )
```

The following function is the main problem (as mentioned below). It should call `texi2dvi` in such a
way that synctex works (for forward and backward syncronization with Okular) and
errors should be displayed in the TeX Help buffer.

```
;; texi2dvi -- define nice function with error handling 
;; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565998/elisp-texi2dvi-how-to-call-texi2dvi-from-emacs/11587555#11587555
(defun mytexi2dvi ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((TeX-save-query nil)
        (TeX-process-asynchronous nil)
        (master-file (expand-file-name (TeX-master-file t)))); append .tex
    (TeX-save-document ""); save document
    ;; run texi2dvi on master
    (TeX-run-TeX "texi2dvi"; name
         (TeX-command-expand
          "texi2dvi -p %s"; command; TODO: errors are not caught ...
          (lambda (ext-ignored nondir)
            (TeX-master-file t nondir)))
                 master-file)
    ;; error handling
    (if (plist-get TeX-error-report-switches (intern master-file))
        (TeX-next-error t)
      (progn
        (demolish-tex-help); that's the function that closes the TeX Help buffer when there is no error anymore (see above)
        (minibuffer-message "texi2dvi: done."))
    )
  )
)
```

For making `mytexi2dvi` available on `C-c C-c`, I use:

```
;; Compiling .tex files
;; adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454839/how-to-add-a-function-latexmk-variant-to-tex-command-list-in-auctex
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
   (lambda ()
     ;; texi2dvi 
     (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
          '("texi2dvi" "(mytexi2dvi)" TeX-run-function nil t :help "Run texi2dvi") t)
     ;; default
     (setq TeX-command-default "latexmk")))
```

Finally, Okular is set up like this:

```
;; set default pdf viewer
;; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29813/setup-synctex-with-emacs
;; Additionally, do: Okular -> Settings -> Editor -> change to Emacs client
(defun Okular-make-url () (concat
               "file://"
               (expand-file-name (funcall file (TeX-output-extension) t)
                         (file-name-directory (TeX-master-file)))
               "#src:"
               (TeX-current-line)
               (expand-file-name (TeX-master-directory))
               "./"
               (TeX-current-file-name-master-relative)))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                  (add-to-list 'TeX-expand-list
                       '("%u" Okular-make-url))))
(setq TeX-view-program-list
     '(("Okular" "okular --unique %u")))
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Okular") (output-dvi "Okular"))); use okular for displaying .pdf and .dvi
```

Interestingly, the following works:

Set in `~/.profile`:

```
PDFLATEX="pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -file-line-error"
export PDFLATEX
```

I can then call `texi2dvi -p foo.tex` in the shell, open Okular via `C-c C-v` and get forward and backward sync, so this is working from the shell.

However, from within Emacs, it's not working. Here are the problems:

1) `C-c C-c` compiles the document, but not `.synctex.gz` is written, so synctex (for backward sync) is not working. This problem remains if I replace `texi2dvi -p %s` by `"PDFLATEX='pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -file-line-error' texi2dvi -p %s"`.

2) On `C-c C-l` I receive `` `No process for this document.'' instead of the
output generated by ``texi2dvi`.

3) In case of an error, no TeX Help buffer is shown, so errors are not
caught/detected.

4) `C-c C-v` opens Okular at the correct spot, so forward sync is working;
backward sync (on `Shift + left mouse`) is not working (as stated above)

Overall, I would consider what I try as a minimal setup to efficiently work with
LaTeX. Since I only found some information and even this quite scattered on the web, I am
wondering how others work with LaTeX/AUCTeX/Emacs? Is there a more efficient
way? The setup above seemed pretty nice to me, you just have to hit `C-c C-c`
(even inside sub-files of a project), the master `.tex` file is compiled (as many times as necessary), and in
case of an error, you directly see what happened. Without the
"close-help-buffer-if-error-is-resolved" I always get confused if I actually
solved the error, that's why I find this useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I could get it to work is by (simply) calling `texi2dvi` directly (without setting up my own function):

```
;; Compiling .tex files
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
   (lambda ()
     ;; texi2dvi 
     (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
          '("texi2dvi" "PDFLATEX='pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -file-line-error' texi2dvi -p %t" TeX-run-command nil t :help "Run texi2dvi") t)
     ;; make
     (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
          '("make" "make" TeX-run-command nil t :help "Run make") t)
     ;; default
     (setq TeX-command-default "texi2dvi")))
```

This does not provide a convenient error-handling as I originally planned to have, but it requires much less hacking and works fine.