# Synctex between Emacs and Evince, which would move focus for backward search

Tags: emacs, auctex, forward-inverse-search, evince

There is a [great way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29813/setup-synctex-with-emacs) to make Emacs, Evince and Synctex work together. However it has a minor caveat: when you do backward search, focus is not moved to Emacs (so you have to do that using mouse or Alt+Tab). This is a slight but nonetheless untoward problem.

In Linux (which I use) there is a CLI utility called [wmctrl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) which can be used to move focus between windows. However I don't know how to add it to the script [mentioned above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29813/setup-synctex-with-emacs), so I decided to ask.

(I believe the main point of this question is using Emacs Lisp so it is *less* relevant to Ask Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code, taken from https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-auctex/2013-04/msg00004.html, to your `.emacs`

```lisp
(defun raise-client-frame ()
  (let ((wmctrl (executable-find "wmctrl")))
    (if wmctrl
    (start-process "wmctrl" nil wmctrl "-R" (frame-parameter nil 'name)))))
;; This raises the frame when using Evince.
(add-hook 'TeX-source-correlate-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (when (TeX-evince-dbus-p)
          (dbus-register-signal
           :session nil "/org/gnome/evince/Window/0"
           "org.gnome.evince.Window" "SyncSource"
           (lambda (file linecol &rest ignored)
         (TeX-source-correlate-sync-source file linecol ignored)
         (raise-client-frame))))))
;; This raises the frame when using all other viewers.
(add-hook 'server-switch-hook 'raise-client-frame)
```

Current version of AUCTeX supports forward/inverse search with Evince out-of-the-box, there is no more need to use old hacks.

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. (I have the latest Ubuntu versions of the three programs installed.)

Comment: @Reza did you restart Emacs after adding that code?

Comment: Yes, I did. Does where you put it in .emacs (w.r.t. the synctex scrip) matter?

Comment: @Reza Ok, you're right, that hook isn't run when Evince is used as viewer (it's run with Okular, the viewer I use).  I'll try another way to answer your question, hold on!

Comment: @Reza  See the updated answer, now this should work for all viewers, Evince included.

Comment: Sorry still doesn't work. I suspect it has to do with the fact that 'wmctrl -R' finds the window based on its title. For me the Emacs window title is the default "emacs24@...". Thanks for your help.

Comment: It works now! I don't know what was the problem but it works now after I restarted my computer.

Comment: @Reza  I'm happy to know that this works now `:-)`

Comment: It works or doesn't work quite randomly. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

```
 (defadvice raise-frame (after make-it-work (&optional frame) activate)
     "Work around some bug? in raise-frame/Emacs/GTK/Metacity/something.
      Katsumi Yamaoka <[hidden email]> posted this in
      http://article.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.devel:39702"
      (call-process
       "wmctrl" nil nil nil "-i" "-R"
       (frame-parameter (or frame (selected-frame)) 'outer-window-id)))
```

Assuming you have `wmctrl` installed on your system, put the above code in your init file.

Source:
http://emacs.1067599.n8.nabble.com/Raising-the-Emacs-frame-in-response-to-a-DBUS-signal-td399111.html