# Extend synctex with emacs to support multiple open pdfs?

Tags: emacs, auctex, forward-inverse-search

Using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78051)  I've been able to get emacs, syntex, and evince to work together almost perfectly to support forward search (tex file -> pdf) and reverse search (pdf -> tex file). The one thing that is missing for me is support for searching from multiple open copies of the pdf.

In more detail, it is my habit when writing technical papers to have multiple copies of the pdf open (using ctrl+n inside evince to open a copy), but when I do this, the opened copy no longer links back to emacs. That is, ctrl+click works in the original pdf opened from emacs, while ctrl+click within the opened copy (created by doing ctrl+n inside evince) has no effect.

My guess is that this might be more of an evince issue than an emacs one, but my question is how can I make it so that reverse searching from the second pdf works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by editing the code for atril. Note there may also exist a yet-to-be-found emacs-based solution.

A little background on how the emacs <--> atril interaction works with regards pdf -> tex searches. In emacs, we listen for messages on the dbus path "/org/mate/atril/Window/0", and atril sends messages on the dbus path  "/org/mate/atril/Window/N"  where N is the window_id of the document (the window_id is incremented each time we do Ctrl+N to open a copy).

Hence the issue is that the copies are sending messages on a dbus path that emacs is not listening to. A hackish way to get this to work is just to have atril always send the synctex commands on the path "/org/mate/atril/Window/0", irrespective of the window_id.

To do this: locate the `ev_window_sync_source` in ev-window.c, and modify the arguments to the `g_dbus_connection_emit_signal` function call that appears in that function. Specifically, it suffices to replace `window->priv->dbus_object_path` with `g_strdup_printf (EV_WINDOW_DBUS_OBJECT_PATH, 0)`. (This applies to the atril 1.18.5 code available on github)

Answer (score 2):

This is inspired by `ttb`'s own solution. The code registering emacs to the dbus signal is in the function `TeX-source-correlate-mode` and looks like this:

```
(dolist (de-app '(("gnome" "evince") ("mate" "atril") ("x" "reader")))     
  (when (TeX-evince-dbus-p (car de-app) (cadr de-app))                     
    (dbus-register-signal                                                  
     :session nil (format "/org/%s/%s/Window/0" (car de-app) (cadr de-app))
     (format "org.%s.%s.Window" (car de-app) (cadr de-app))                
     "SyncSource"                                                          
     'TeX-source-correlate-sync-source)))
```

So (as a hacky solution) you can just run the same code with `0` replaced by `i` for as many `i` as you think you will have windows open at the same time.

So, altogether, I put the following in my `.emacs` file:

```
(defun my/add-ten-more-synctex-windows ()
  (dotimes (i 10)
    (dolist (de-app '(("gnome" "evince") ("mate" "atril") ("x" "reader")))
      (when (TeX-evince-dbus-p (car de-app) (cadr de-app))
        (dbus-register-signal
         :session nil (format "/org/%s/%s/Window/%d" (car de-app) (cadr de-app) (1+ i))
         (format "org.%s.%s.Window" (car de-app) (cadr de-app))
         "SyncSource"
         'TeX-source-correlate-sync-source)))))                              
   
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-source-correlate-mode)                                                                                      
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my/add-ten-more-synctex-windows)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The above solution by Joj is very nice. But it goes one way, i.e., multiple evince windows point to multiple  emacs buffers. Is it possible to extend the solution to also go the reverse way, i.e. if I click on a specific emacs buffer it goes to a specific evince window. Right now when I click on either emacs buffer, it only goes to the original evince window and not the copy of the evince window.  [Sorry: this is a question/comment, not an answer]

Comment: Indeed, it's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/221536)